# angular material. ripple not work with small button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material, ripple

I have this code:

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-fab md-button">
  <md-icon md-font-icon>
    add
  </md-icon>
</md-button>
```

It's simple smal button 56x56 px and ripple not work correctly for this. 
Then i set width and height more that 202px for this button and ripple works correctly.
What did i do wrong?

Comment: What version of material design do you have? when i try it out the ripple seems to work: http://codepen.io/Tyre88/pen/QyEmWN

Comment: 1.0.0. Latest from bower.

Comment: i found problem. I use fixed sidebar. But i don't understand why it works so.

Comment: No. Fixed sidebar is not problem. I think i had not to use md-sidenav without md-content.

Comment: Victor Öhrström thank you for true way.